# web2py adding username validation

Tags: python, authentication, web2py

I have just started to look at web2py and wish to use username rather than email to log in.

I have added the following :-

```
auth.define_tables(username=True, signature=False)
```

and I need to add the validator, but I don't know where to put it (sounds silly I know).

I have tried a few options and looked at many examples - but they all create a new table rather than use the existing auth_user.
I tried :-

```
auth_table = auth.settings.table_user
auth_table.username.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, auth_table.username)
auth.define_tables(username=True, signature=False)
```

But auth_table is None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auth.settings.table_user` will not exist until after you call `auth.define_tables()`. So, just change the order of your code:

```
auth.define_tables(username=True, signature=False)
auth_table = auth.settings.table_user
auth_table.username.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, auth_table.username)
```

Note, if you define your `db` object with `DAL(..., lazy_tables=True)`, auth.settings.table_user will not exist. In that case, you can instead do `auth_table = auth.table_user()`.